# How to publish primefaces jar to maven local?

Tags: maven, primefaces, publish

build jar from primefaces source

```
mvn clean install
```

How to publish the primefaces jar to maven local?
what is mvn command for publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `install` "publishes" the JAR to the local Maven repository.